# Why is ACM's DNS validation stuck?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

My SSL certificate is stuck at Pending Validation. It eventually fails and times out after few days.

[image]

I own my domain on Route 53 and added the CNAME record in the newly created Public Hosted Zone. While requesting a certificate, I put fully qualifed domain name as `watsky1337.link`. I tried `*.watsky1337.link` but that also didn't change the outcome.

My cloudformation template for creating the certificate request:

```
{
   "Resources":{
      "MyCertificate":{
         "Type":"AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
         "Properties":{
            "DomainName":"*.watsky1337.link",
            "ValidationMethod":"DNS"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And, cloudformation template for adding CNAME record to the Public Hosted Zone:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "myDNSRecord": {
      "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
      "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneId": "Z01832163FDLRM2C7PVYW",
        "Name": "_42fb819b92f98e5ef699548b8d5a52df.watsky1337.link",
        "ResourceRecords": [
          "_13b8185f6fa218a71d9fbb82bfbe705c.ndlxkpgcgs.acm-validations.aws."
        ],
        "Type": "CNAME",
        "TTL": "900"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a detailed view of the Certificate

[image]

And here are the record sets in this hosted zone

[image]

I have the required permissions to do all this because this is my own personal AWS account.

I tried to troubleshoot it by checking if my nameservers are visible if I check it on CLI but they aren't. What am I doing wrong?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/gnbQBFx.png]

Comment: When you say you "own the domain in Route53" does that mean you went over to the domains section of Route53 (not the hosted zones section) and purchased the domain there?

Comment: Yes, right. I bought it on Route 53. Route 53 is my DNS registrar.

Comment: Then you need to make sure the name server records in the DNS registrar section match the name server records in the hosted zone.

Comment: Although really something should be coming back already for that DNS query. Are you sure the Domain registration is completed? What is the status value of the domain over on the registrar side?

Comment: thanks, I just compared the nameservers of public hosted zone with the ones in registrar. They do not match. It's highly likely this is the problem, I have updated it now. Also got this prompt: "Your request to update nameserver was successfully submitted. You will receive an email when it is done."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Mark B's comment, I changed the nameservers in registrar to the ones in public hosted zone so that they're same.

[image]

[image]

And now my Certificate's status is issued:

[image]

Nameservers are also visible now:

[image]